# Can I print a single answer?

Tags: support, printing

After looking around on the page, I couldn't find any print link or anything that would indicate such functionality; but, I'm hoping a power user knows something that I don't.

Comment: **POWER USER - POWER MOVE!** hehe... Try [this](http://www.stackprinter.com/) - might help you out... It was made by one of our [very own users](http://stackoverflow.com/users/130929/systempuntoout).  It won't allow you to print a single answer - but you'll be able to extract the data you want.

Comment: @Lix Thanks, I like it. Yeah, I was hoping for a single answer (ya know, SAVE THE TREES!), but that definitely helps.

Comment: Printing on **PAPER**?? How 1990 of you ;)

Comment: @Lix I was gonna suggest StackPrinter, but you'd already done so.. Convert to an answer?

Comment: Oh, if you sit tight for a while I'll write a userscript for it that gives you an easy print button om any post. But I may write it tomorrow (not on comp atm)

Comment: That's funny. I was just thinking about printing answers. Then I was thinking of making a formatting user script. Then, as if the universe heard my thoughts, this got bumped to the front page. Excellent.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Userscript alert!

This adds a "print" link to each post. All it does is kill everything except the post and bring it to the top of the page.

[Enjoy!](https://stackapps.com/questions/3307/print-this-post)

Comment: Nice! This is EXACTLY what I had in mind.

Answer (score 14):

[StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) is a service created by [one of our very own!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130929/systempuntoout).  From a question ID it will allow you to save a PDF document containing all the information within that post including -

- The question
- The answer[s]
- The comment[s]

Once you have the PDF you could extract the information you are looking for.

Not an optimal solution but It might help you get started.

Generally you would want the question to come with the answer, otherwise you might end up printing a big **42** on a piece of paper :)

---

Another option would be to use one of the [free URL to PDF convertors](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+url+to+pdf).  The [first result](http://www.html-to-pdf.net/free-online-pdf-converter.aspx) I got actually gave me a PDF file **with all the hyperlinks intact**!

---

Printing an answer by id is now supported on [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com).
Here is an example:
http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=128703&service=meta.stackexchange&answer=128707

Check the [Api doc](http://www.stackprinter.com/docs/api.txt) for more information.

Comment: @systempuntoout awesome! Thanks for the updates

Answer (score 1):

You can click `edit` at the bottom of the answer/question you wish to isolate, copy the whole text that makes it, and paste it to [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/editor). Then print it from there by either exporting it or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

you can make it with your Browser too.
and the better way is you copy your Useful answer in your self Document, and then Printing that.