# Printing an answer on a single page

Tags: feature-request, answers, printing

I wanted to print an answer for reference purposes. Is there any way to get just an answer on a page, without the question or other answers?

Comment: Does your print dialog not contain an option to only print the selected text?

Comment: No. Obviously can choose pages but nothing that fancy.

Comment: Chrome can do it for example

Comment: Whoa it does! I'll add an answer thanks.

Comment: Copy paste doesn't work for you?

Comment: Copy paste to where? I could past to Google Docs or something maybe, not sure if formatting is always preserved. The selection solves it anyway.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128703/

Answer (score 7):

Seems there's no direct link to just the answer, but as Bart mentions in comments, Chrome print dialog, when "more settings" is revealed, lets you print just a selection, so that's a good workaround.

> Chrome/Chromium : select your text > File > Print… > More settings > Selection only

It looks like it preserves the content well enough.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can also right-click on selected text and select "Print" in the context menu to print the highlighted text. It's slightly faster. I frequently do that by mistake when I want to google selected text.